# I got an error in else part! You have entered 2 times like that

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Visiting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h2>Visit</h2></center>
    <hr size=15>
    <br><br><br>
    <form name=form1 method="post"><br>
        <center>
            Enter your name:
            <input type=text name=na><br><br><br>
            <input type=button value=click onClick="checks(this.form)">
        </center>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
   c=2;
    function checks(form)
    {
        var s=document.cookie;
        document.cookie=form1.na.value;
        if((s==null)||(s!=form1.na.value))
        {
            window.alert(form1.na.value+" you have entered first time");
            form1.na.value=" ";
        }
        else
        {
            window.alert(form1.na.value+" you have entered "+c+" times");
            c=c+1;
            form1.na.value=" ";
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I didn't get the output "how my times you have entered".

I think the error in else programming part.

Not able to find out my problems.

Please help me to get output.

Comment: You have to declare `c` first as a variable. Add `var` before `c=2`.

Comment: Can you provide the full code here (not as an image)? And please be more specific with your error, so it becomes easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

And if it is not possible then you need to use localStorage instead of cookie.

Reference link : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");


<script>
        c = 2;
        function checks(form) {
            var s = localStorage.getItem("value");
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("value", form1.na.value);
            if ((s == null) || (s != form1.na.value)) {
                window.alert(form1.na.value + " you have entered first time");
                form1.na.value = " ";
            }
            else {
                window.alert(form1.na.value + " you have entered " + c + " times");
                c = c + 1;
                form1.na.value = " ";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

If you have any value repeatedly then you got it your message "You have entered X times".

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `c` first as a variable. Add `var` before `c=2`.

Change row 18 to:

```
var c = 2;
```